# rest api how do you express the nested structure?

Tags: rest, django-rest-framework, restful-url

rest api how do you express the nested structure?

I'm using case number one now.
But I'm trying to change it to case number three.

The reason is that I am using drf_yasg to create a document, but the nested structure in Case 1 could not be created automatically, so I had to create it manually.

I am mainly curious what case you use.

**case 1**: GET /users/test@test.com/addresses

```
{
    "email":"test@test.com",

    "addresses":[

        {
            "id" : 1,

            "zipcode": "00000",

        },

        {
            "id" : 2,

            "zipcode": "00000",

        }

    ]

}
```

**case 2**: GET /users/test@test.com/addresses

```
[

    {
        "id" : 1,

        "zipcode": "00000",

    },

    {
        "id" : 2,

        "zipcode": "00000",

    }

]
```

**case 3**: GET /addresses?user__email=test@test.com

```
[

    {
        "id" : 1,

        "zipcode": "00000",

    },

    {
        "id" : 2,

        "zipcode": "00000",

    }

]
```

Comment: You can try using userID instead of email addresses

Comment: @Swaraj Gandhi  The case above is just a test case. 
I am mainly curious what case you use.

Comment: I preferred the last one, writing email in the url path does not look good, if you have specific value from you want to get the output, prefer to pass it in query params